# Sequelize unsigned zerofill not working wit MySql

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

i have unique ids in database which starts from 000001 and also have auto increment on ids ( **unsigned autofill**)

**in sequelize model**

```
id:DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED.AUTOFILL   //not working
```

//also tried below

`id: DataTypes.INTEGER.AUTOFILL.UNSIGNED`  //not working

```
id: DataTypes.INTEGER(6).AUTOFILL.UNSIGNED  //not working
```

**sequelize version : 5.21.4**

**but i am getting ids like 1,2,3 instead of 000001,000002,000003**

please tell me where i am doing it wrong

Comment: a) not explaining what "not working" means - its a horrible phrase for a help request that fails to explain the desired and actual results. b) expecting zerofill to work - its an antiquated thing better dealt with in the presentation layer rather than SQL.

Comment: i am getting ids like 1,2,3 instead of 000001,000002,000003

Comment: how you assigned zerofill in mySql DB